# How to add linker directories to cmake gtest_discover_tests

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, googletest

I'm using cmake and gtest for my project.
My gtest executable is using the same name as the program executable. I know this is not ideal but I cannot change it.

The compiler I'm using is installed in a different directory than the system GCC (which is older).
I've set the compiler path using:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/gcc-5.4.0/bin/gcc-5.4.0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/gcc-5.4.0/bin/g++-5.4.0)
```

When linking my executable I'm using target_link_directories:

```
target_link_directories(target PUBLIC /opt/gcc-5.4.0/lib /opt/gcc-5.4.0/lib64)
```

Without gtest, the target compiles, links and runs properly, however when adding gtest:

```
  gtest_discover_tests(target WORKING_DIRECTORY <gtests_soruce_dir>)
```

The gtest target fails to link:

```
target: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by executable_name)
target: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by executable_name)
target: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by executable_name)
target: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by executable_name)

CMake Error at /home/gilkalish/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/202.6397.106/bin/cmake/linux/share/cmake-3.17/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:40 (message):
  Error running test executable.

    Path: 'executable_path'
    Result: 1
    Output:
```

This is the very last step while linking gtest, after the executable was linked.

```
/usr/bin/cmake3 -D TEST_TARGET=target -D TEST_EXECUTABLE=<target_path>/target -D TEST_EXECUTOR= -D TEST_WORKING_DIR=<test_path> -D TEST_EXTRA_ARGS= -D TEST_PROPERTIES= -D TEST_PREFIX= -D TEST_SUFFIX= -D NO_PRETTY_TYPES=FALSE -D NO_PRETTY_VALUES=FALSE -D TEST_LIST=target_TESTS -D CTEST_FILE=target[1]_tests.cmake -D TEST_DISCOVERY_TIMEOUT=5 -P
```

I can add the path to my custom GCC libraries using LD_LIBRARY_PATH, then linking works, but I would like to find a solution that will allow me to specify in cmake where to look for that libraries when linking the tests.

Also tried updating to cmake 3.18 that gave the same results.
Any tips will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: check your make VERBOSE=1 and see what is the link line

Comment: @kobi when using VERBOSE=1 I can see the cmake command mentioned above (last code section), not the actual linking commands. This is only happening with the gtest cmake module. I'll dig into this gtest cmake module.

Comment: this is strange. you should see a link command.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR problem solved when I asked CMake to use the install RPATH during the build process by using

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH ON)
```

Some more details:
The CMake GTest module is running the executable to enumerate the tests after it was linked during `make` (not quite sure why). This is failing because at this point the install RPATH was not set yet. It is only set during `make install`
To overcome this, you can ask CMake to add the install RPATH during build time.

Comment: Where exactly did you put this command (which CMakeLists.txt in the heirarchy, and before/after what specific other commands within that txt)? I am having a similar issue when I place my unit tests in a sub directory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694001/how-do-i-correct-my-cmakelists-txt-so-my-project-builds-on-both-linux-and-window

Comment: I added it in the top level cmake file but as long as it is before gtest_discover_tests I believe it should work