# How do I correct my CMakeLists.txt so my project builds on both linux and windows?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, googletest

I am on a project that I recently added a new feature and accompanying unit tests to. The structure of the project looks like this:

```
Sim
└── models
    ├── otherModels
    └── myModel
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── model.cpp
        ├── model.h
        ├── test
        │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
        │   ├── geometryTest.cpp
        │   └── geometryTest.h
        └── util
            ├── CMakeLists.txt
            ├── geometry.cpp
            ├── geometry.h
            └── probability.h
```

## Summarize the problem

My goal is to be able to build said project and execute the unit tests both on windows and linux.

### Actual Results

On Windows, I am able to build the project and run the unit tests just fine.

On linux, I get an error while building saying that the library being tested cannot be found:

```
/home/e40056742/projects/xxxx/build/make-Release/Sim/bin/modelTests: error while loading shared libraries: libmathUtil.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
CMake Error at /projs/xxxx/cmake-3.18.2/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:77 (message):
  Error running test executable.

    Path: '/home/e40056742/projects/xxxx/build/make-Release/Sim/bin/modelTests'
    Result: 127
    Output:


Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /projs/xxxx/cmake-3.18.2/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/GoogleTestAddTests.cmake:173 (gtest_discover_tests_impl)


make[2]: *** [Sim/bin/modelTests] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file `Sim/bin/modelTests'
make[1]: *** [Sim/src/models/myModel/test/CMakeFiles/modelTests.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

### Expected Results

To be able to build on linux.

## What I've tried

1. I googled how to find a file on linux and verified that the file exists:

   ```
   find . -name libmathUtil.so
   >>> ./build/make-Release/Sim/lib/libmathUtil.so
   ```
2. I verified that everything builds on linux if I comment out `add_subdirectory(test)`
3. I tried the solution posted here to a different (but I hoped related) question: [How to add linker directories to cmake gtest_discover_tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63402829/how-to-add-linker-directories-to-cmake-gtest-discover-tests/66394189#66394189)
4. I added CMake RPATH settings to my test directory's CMakeLists.txt, as suggested in another answer: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling#always-full-rpath
5. I tried to correctly set up the CMakeLists.txt files like so:

**Top level CMake for my working directory**

```
set( target myCoolModel )

set( sources
    model.cpp
    )

set( headers
    model.h
    )

add_library( ${target} ${sources} ${headers} )

target_link_libraries( ${target}
    ${PROJECT_LIBRARIES}
    mathUtil
    )

# Group the target library into an IDE folder
set_target_properties( ${target} PROPERTIES FOLDER ${PROJECT_FOLDER} )

# Add the utility and test subdirectory 
enable_testing()
add_subdirectory( util )
add_subdirectory( test )
```

**And in the `util` sub-directory:**

```
set( target mathUtil)
set( sources geometry.cpp )
set( headers geometry.h probability.h)

add_library( ${target} ${sources} ${headers} )

target_link_libraries( ${target} genMath::genMath )

target_compile_options( ${target} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_CXX_FLAGS} )

target_include_directories( ${target}
    PUBLIC  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
```

**And the `test` directory:**

```
enable_testing()

# Set target name, and dependencies
set( target modelTests )
set( sources geometryTest.cpp )
set( headers geometryTest.h)

# Find Google Test
find_package( GTest REQUIRED )

# Make test executable. 
add_executable( ${target} ${sources} ${headers} )

target_link_libraries(${target}
    mathUtil
    GTest::gtest_main
)

# Load GoogleTest and add these tests to the suite
include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(${target})

# File unit tests into the project test folder (makes it easier to find in solution explorer)
set( PROJECT_FOLDER ${PROJECT_FOLDER}/test )
set_target_properties( ${target} PROPERTIES FOLDER ${PROJECT_FOLDER} )
```

Comment: The error you mentioned is not a build error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely failing because `gtest_discover_tests` by default actually runs the test executable at build stage to get the list of tests available. The environment, especially `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, may not be properly set up for the executable to run.

If nothing else works, and you have CMake>=3.18, you can delay the discovery of tests (exclude from the build stage), by setting the `DISCOVERY_MODE` to `PRE_TEST`. Quote from the [document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html):

> **DISCOVERY_MODE**
>
> New in version 3.18.
>
> Provides greater control over when gtest_discover_tests() performs
> test discovery. By default, POST_BUILD sets up a post-build command to
> perform test discovery at build time. In certain scenarios, like
> cross-compiling, this POST_BUILD behavior is not desirable. By
> contrast, PRE_TEST delays test discovery until just prior to test
> execution. This way test discovery occurs in the target environment
> where the test has a better chance at finding appropriate runtime
> dependencies.

I actually tried to get the test discovery run in `POST_BUILD` mode by setting the correct environment variables using the `PROPERTIES` of `google_discover_tests`, but nothing worked and after examining the source code of `GoogleTest` cmake module itself I have concluded that it is not possible to set up the environment variables for the shell session where `google_discover_tests` runs the test executable on your behalf.

The only other feasible alternative without using `PRE_TEST` is to setup the `RPATH` for the executable properly so that it can find the dependencies all by its own. However conventionally in CMake the `RPATH` should be set in the install stage rather than build stage. Also extracting the correct paths from a `find_package` call and then adding them to the `RPATH` is not always trivial and is error-prone. That's why I ended up with `PRE_TEST` even though I really prefer `POST_BUILD` if it can be done in a simple way.

Comment: Setting DISCOVER_MODE to PRE_TEST did indeed allow our automated build pipelines to finish on both RHEL7 and RHEL8 systems!

I also would prefer to use default settings, I guess POST_BUILD, but I'm not installing anything, and as you mentioned that seems to be integral to setting RPATH. 

In all actuality all of these things are very confusing to me even after pouring over the documentation, so thank you for your help and thank you for making it explicit enough for me to understand and use.

Answer (score 0):

The error in question sounds like it's happening at run time, rather than build time.  I will answer based on that assumption:

The file `./build/make-Release/Sim/lib/libmathUtil.so` is not in a directory pointed to by [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environment-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux), and the elf header for `modelTests` lacks an `RPATH` entry that points to your library (verifiable using `readelf -d modelTests`, documentation on how to set `RPATH` in cmake [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling)).

With neither means of directing where to find shared objects being employed, the library cannot be found at run time.

Comment: The error occurs during the build process and causes the build to fail. It may be that the test executable is trying to run during the build process, which was not my intention but could make your statement true. I will dive into the links and accept your answer if the links provide an answer to my question.